# How to get image format? (not from file extension)

Tags: android, image

I want to know what format some image file is. There are actually only 2 or 3 possible options: jpeg, png and possibly bmp, but the file extension is always png. How to get the actual format of that image on android?

Comment: Read the header and compare it to the different standards. They are usually just a few bytes/characters in size and provide enough information about the format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hexadecimal codes:

- JPEG image files begin with `FF D8 FF E0` or `FF D8 FF DB`
- PNG image files begin with `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`
- BMP image files begin with `42 4D`

If you're certain only three file formats will be used, you just need the first byte to differentiate them!